# Why can't Haskell optimize this duplicate function call?

Tags: haskell

In my Haskell code i use a function that gets very often called and looks like this:

```
doSomething x y = (a, b)
where a = expensive1 x y
      b = expensive2 x y a
```

Compiled with GHC 8.10.3 and -O2 my program takes about 45 seconds to run.
However if i write the same function like this:

```
doSomething x y = (a, b)
where a = expensive1 x y
      b = expensive2 x y (expensive1 x y)
```

my program takes about 60 seconds to run.

Shouldn't the compiler recognize the duplicate call of `expensive1 x y` and optimize it away? `expensive1` and `expensive2` are pure functions, so recalculating `expensive1 x y` shouldn't be necessary. Or is the GC too aggressive and garbage collects `a` before before `b` is needed later?

Comment: Without optimizations, `length [1..n] + length [1..n]` runs in constant space, `let xs=[1..n] in length xs + length xs` does not. An optimizer should not turn the first one into the second by removing the duplicate.

Comment: (And before you complain that `let m = length [1..n] in m+m` runs in constant space, consider `length [1..n] + last [1..n]`.)

Answer (score 7):

It is a tradeoff. The optimization you propose reduces runtime but increases memory usage. It's way too hard to automatically get that tradeoff right every time, so the programmer is given control of it -- name a thing, and it's shared, don't name it, and it's recomputed.

(...mostly. As always with these things, it's complicated. But this is the 10km view of the answer.)

By the way, the name of this optimization is "common subexpression elimination". Googling that should get you quite a lot more information about different compilers' choices in this domain.

Comment: GHC does actually perform CSE (it's one of the optimisation passes listed [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fcse)), even for unnamed expressions, I think.

Comment: @oisdk yes, but it's very conservative about it, precisely because as said in the answer, it can actually have detrimental memory impact. (As well as blowing up compilation times – full general CSE requires solving the halting problem, you can only ever get heuristics.)

Comment: @oisdk As I said in the answer... it's complicated. ^_^